# Using the jQuery $ prefix with TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm trying to cast my html input control to a HTMLInputElement in typescript. Trying to access the input control through the normal shorthand jQuery method,

```
e.g. <HTMLInputElement> $("#CompareToControl")
```

results in a squiggly red line error "Neither type JQuery nor type HTMLInputElement are assignable to each other.

Is there any way of getting this to work, or are we forced to use the old longhand way of referencing controls e.g.

```
 <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("CompareToControl");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `$(expn)` does not return a DOM element instead it returns a JQuery Object and they are not assignable to each other. So you would need to get the DOM element from jquery object to be of type `HTMLInputElement`. i.e

```
<HTMLInputElement> $("#CompareToControl")[0]
```

The typing declaration for `$(expn)` that you are using is as follows. (`$` is of type JQueryStatic)

```
interface JQueryStatic {
     /**
     * Accepts a string containing a CSS selector which is then used to match a set of elements.
     *
     * @param selector A string containing a selector expression
     * @param context A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context
     */
    (selector: string, context?: JQuery): JQuery;
}
```